# Can RubyMine IDE recognize rspec tests if filename does not have _spec suffix?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

Let me preface this by saying I am a newbie to Ruby.

I am doing an extremely basic tutorial on Ruby in RubyMine, and as part of the tutorial, we create a class in a .rb Ruby file called thing.rb.  In addition to the class, the tutorial has us put an Rspec test in the same .rb file.  The .rb file looks like the following:

```
require 'rspec'

class Thing
    def value
        5
    end
end

describe Thing do
    it "should have a value of 6" do
        Thing.new.value.should eq(7)
    end
end
```

If I right-click the project folder and "Run all specs in the project", I get errors and messages including "0 files found" and "Empty test suite."  If I just run the rb script, I get no errors...the script runs fine.

The STRANGE thing is that if I add a second file to the project called thing_spec.rb and put in it only the test from above:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'thing'

describe Thing do
    it "should have a value of 6" do
        Thing.new.value.should eq(7)
    end
end
```

And then right-click the project and select "Run all specs," the tests run fine. Notice I said the tests (plural)...RubyMine will run the test in thing.rb AND the test in thing_spec.rb.

Why won't it recognize the test in thing.rb without my having to add a second file called thing_spec.rb??  This makes no sense to me.  Is there anyway I could have it run the rspec tests from within thing.rb without having to create a second file?

In case it is important: I work on a Mac, have RubyMine version 4.5, using ruby interpreter 1.9.3, rspec 2.12.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you go in `Run > Edit Configurations...`

And select `All Specs in <Your Project>` you'll see Filename Mask: `**/*_spec.rb`

This means when you tell RubyMine to run "All Specs", it only runs files which match the regex.

Now when you add second file and you do `require_relative` to load the other one, so both the tests run.